# i have a listview and i want to perform action of the adapter item into the fragment class ! how can i do this?

Tags: android

This is my `getview` method I want to find `textview` (viewHolder.tv_number) in my fragment class . How can i do this?

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (view == null) {
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.category, parent, false);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.Dish_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nameofdish);
        viewHolder.dish_description = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dishdescription);
        viewHolder.Dish_rate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rateofdish);
        viewHolder.item_image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_item);
        viewHolder.tv_Number = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_add_sub);
        viewHolder.mBtnAdd = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
        viewHolder.mBtnMinus = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_sub);
    } 
}
```

Comment: dear this is the method of the adapter class ! my problem is i can i find the textview of the adapter class in my fragment class !

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
//set adapter class
    customButtonListener customListner;

        public interface customButtonListener {
            public void onClickButton(int position);
        }

        public void setCustomButtonListner(customButtonListener listener) {
            this.customListner = listener;
        }

    //set click listner

    viewHolder.mBtnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                               customListner.onClickButton(pass data);
                        }
                    });

    //Implement in adapter 

    adapter.setCustomButtonListner(Fragment.this);

    //Overide method

    @Override
        public void onClickButton(String song_id)
        {
           // Your custom click event here...
        }
```